# Warning for header information in my test server but not in local why?

Tags: php

I have my site live in which i echoed few strings for testing, so it displayed me those test strings but along with the warning message

> Warning: Cannot modify header
>   information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/companyfolder/public_html/mycart.php:117)
>   in
>   /home/companyfolder/public_html/includes/functions/general.php
>   on line 50

But at the same time i do not get this error any where in my local machine so i want to know is there any difference in display of header information related to servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of output buffering

And not a single one, who volunteered to share their knowledge about error handling, mentioned a way more likely reason - display_errors turned off, as it on the live site ought to be.

Of course it should be. To

- not to scare users with strange messages
- not to reveal vital info of your application to possible attacker. nor to supply them with any feedback.
- inform a programmer of **all** errors occurred, by turning `log_errors` setting on

Thus, on a development site

```
display_errors = on
log_errors = off
```

on a live site

```
display_errors = off
log_errors = on
```

while error reporting *level* should remain the same - E_ALL or better

Comment: Is it good practice to make display_errors turned off on live site?

Comment: @OM it's the only possible choice. An obligatory rule. See an updated answer for fancy formatted explanation.

Comment: While display_errors() most certainly should be turned off on a production server, "test" and "local machine" both imply development environments where you would certainly *not* want display_errors() disabled.

Comment: +1 I like the way you reply, I call this "Reply in Sarcastic Way" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have the same issue in both places, just different error reporting levels. You can configure this in your php.ini file or at runtime with [error_reporting()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0):

This error is pretty general, but basically what is happening is what it says. You're including mycart.php in a page and on like 117 it starts outputting HTML (or something client-side), once this starts happening you can't modify any of the header information (ex. a redirect). Like jason said though, the reason the error isn't showing up is the error_reporting setting.

EDIT: You can solve some of these problems by using ob_start() and then ob_end_flush() after you've done your header modifying.

Comment: And if they have one, it must be solved with proper application design, not a dirty patch. Output buffering is a tool, for it's own purpose, not to conceal holes in application design. Good planned application will never output anything before headers being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your other server configuration might have `output buffering` turned on in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

The server has this in php.ini

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

if you just want errors then use

```
  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Comment: nobody wants error_reporting at any level other than E_ALL or E_STRICT